# Alter Laravel 5.2 email reset link functionality

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, reset-password

I am trying to override the `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker::emailResetLink()` method in Laravel 5.2 to change the behavior. I have to send the reset link and the user email to third party service which will deliver the reset password email.

I have tried to change the binding for `auth.password.broker` like this:

```
// $this->app->bind('auth.password.broker', 'App\Auth\MyPasswordBroker');

$this->app->bind('auth.password.broker', function(){
     dd('BROKER');
});
```

Well it was unsuccessful. It's not triggered and I cannot find a way to alter the method.

Comment: Where did you register the binding?

Comment: In `AppServiceProvider::boot()`

Comment: Ok, what instance do you get when you dump the binding after overriding it? Try `dd(app('auth.password.broker'));` right after you register the binding. Also, make sure your `AppServiceProvider` is registered **after** `Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider`. If your closure isn't dumped, then your binding is being overridden somewhere, though not sure where...

Comment: It's definitely not catching my binding and the `dd` shows the default `PasswordBroker` class. The `AppServiceProvider` is nearly last in the array of providers

Comment: Strange... I experience the same thing locally. Give me a moment.

Comment: I'm stumped. The stock password broker is deferred so I'm not sure when it's being resolved. Sorry I couldn't be more help!